# Gumstix, uvc_camera and cv_capture

Tags: ros, vision-opencv, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've observed something surprising with a small UVC camera on the
gumstix overo. If I use the camera_node from uvc_camera, I get barely
2 fps in 640x480.
On the other hand, if I make a small application using the opencv
cvCapture function, I get close to 10fps at the same resolution.

Here is the cv code in all its complexity:

```
       CvCapture* capture = 0;
       capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( -1 );
       IplImage *cv_image = NULL;
       ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
       while (ros::ok())
       {
           cv_image = cvQueryFrame(capture);
           try {
               image_pub_.publish(bridge_.cvToImgMsg(cv_image, "bgr8"));
           } catch (sensor_msgs::CvBridgeException error) {
               ROS_ERROR("error");
           }
           ros::spinOnce();
           loop_rate.sleep();
       }

       cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
```

On the same camera on my laptop, both cv_capture and uvc_camera
publish at 10 fps.

I guess that means there is something that would need optimisation in
the uvc_camera/camera_node, but for now I'll be fine with just
reporting :-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9055/gumstix,-uvc_camera-and-cv_capture/) by [Tully](https://answers.ros.org/users/7/tully/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2011-02-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen similar discrepancies in performance from the driver based on computer as well. See http://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20110105.220655.b7e05812.en.html (though in that situation, all of the computers in question had enough CPU horsepower to not drop the framerate).

Could you report which camera you are using? Also, no idea if you can get a monitor on the overo, but if you can, you could use guvcview to see if that also experiences a slow down in frame rate when you try to use similar settings to the uvc_camera driver.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2